# Object selection in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, viewer, forge

I have created the sample application for forge viewer.

I am  able to view  the Revit and navisworks files in forge viewer.

I want to select an item from the viewer by passing inputs to viewer.bubble.search method.

I am using the same coding from the url:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/BubbleNode/

I am using the below code. Please help.

```
var viewer;
 var urn1;
 var accestoken1;
 var jsdata;

 function uploadfile(file) {
     document.getElementById('<%=UploadBtn.ClientID%>').click();
 }

 function showModel(urn) {
     var options = {
         env: 'AutodeskProduction',
         getAccessToken: getForgeToken
     };

     Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
         viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('forgeViewer'), { extensions: ['Autodesk.DocumentBrowser'] });
         viewer.start();
         var documentId = 'urn:' + urn;
         urn1 = urn;
         Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
        // viewer.fitToView([270005], viewer.model);
        // viewer.select([270005]);
     });

 }

 function myFunction1() {
     setTimeout(function () {
         myFunction2();
     }, 500);
 }


 function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {                 
     var viewables = viewer.bubble.search({ type: 'geometry', role: '3d', name: 'DOMW PIPE' });

     if (viewables.length === 0) {
         console.error('Document contains no viewables.');
         return;
     }
 }

 function onDocumentLoadFailure(viewerErrorCode) {
     console.error('onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:' + viewerErrorCode);
 }

 function getForgeToken(callback) {
     fetch('/api/forge/oauth/token').then(res => {
         res.json().then(data => {
             callback(data.access_token, data.expires_in);
             accestoken1 = data.access_token;
         });
     });
 }
```

with thanks and regards.

Castro Nelson

Comment: What exactly do you need to search for in the `BubbleNode`? Note that this class contains information about the different 3D views and 2D views that were extracted from your original design file.

Comment: Note that there's an extension available in the viewer called `DocumentBrowser` that can be used to switch between different 2D/3D views from the bubble. Take a look at the https://forge-extensions.autodesk.io demo, open one of the sample files, and then, in the _Built-in_ tab on the right side, activate the _DocumentBrowser_ extension.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to make it possible to choose which of the 2D or 3D views (that the Model Derivative service extracted from your original design) to load in the viewer, consider using the built-in viewer extension called `Autodesk.DocumentBrowser`. The extension will add a new UI to the viewer that can be used to switch between the different 2D/3D views quite easily.

You can experiment with the extension on https://forge-extensions.autodesk.io:
[image]